# Primefaces chart + jqplot extender - rounded value in the y-axis

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, graph, primefaces, jqplot

**Background**

I have a primefaces line chart (date on x, integer >= 0 on y) extended with jqplot options:

```
function extender() {
        this.cfg.axes = {
            xaxis : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
                rendererOptions : {
                    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                },
                tickOptions : { 
                    fontSize:'10pt',
                    fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                    angle:-40,                     
                    formatString:'%b-%y'
                },
                tickInterval:'2592000000'
            },
            yaxis : {
                min: 0,
                rendererOptions : {
                    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                },
                tickOptions: {
                    fontSize:'10pt', 
                    fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                    angle:0,
                    formatString: '%d'
                }
            },
        };
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.ticks = this.cfg.categories;
    }
```

I'm using the jqplot extender to have custom date interval on the x-axis and this is working fine:

[image: Working fine]

**Problem**

When I use the option `min: 0` in the y-axis the formatting of numbers goes really funky, especially when there are small values:

[image: Fraction number]

Note that the `minY` attribute in primefaces doesn't work (probably because the extender overwrites it)

To fix that, I use `formatString: %d`. It works but it creates problem with the number of ticks:

[image]

As you see on the screenshot, there are several times the line for the value 1.

**Question**

How can make sure I don't get several times the same value on the y-axis?

I can't really have a static number of ticks because when the data grows large (let's say around 100), I do want several values on the y-axis (e.g 20, 40, etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue using ideas from Mehasse's post.

Defining the `max` value like suggested by Mehasse didn't remove the unwanted tick lines but helped me to find the answer.

By default, primefaces/jqplot wants to have `4` y-axis tick lines. Thus, if the max value is below `4`, there will be duplication in the y-axis label when they are rounded up (`formatString: '%d'`).

What I basically want, is the tick interval to be either `Max(y) \ 4` when `Max(y) > 4`, or `1` otherwise:

```
function actionPlanExtender() {
        var series_max =maxSeries(this.cfg.data);
        var numberOfTicks =4;
        var tickInterval = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(series_max/numberOfTicks));
        this.cfg.axes = {
            xaxis : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
                rendererOptions : {
                    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                },
                tickOptions : { 
                    fontSize:'10pt',
                    fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                    angle:-40,                     
                    formatString:'%b-%y'
                },
                tickInterval:'2592000000'
            },
            yaxis : {
                min: 0,
                rendererOptions : {
                    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                },
                tickOptions: {
                    fontSize:'10pt', 
                    fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                    angle:0,
                    formatString: '%d',
                },
                tickInterval: tickInterval
            },
        };
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.ticks = this.cfg.categories;
    }
```

To compute the y-max value, I'm getting the plot value using `this.cfg.data` which is of the form `[series_1,..., series_n]` with `series_i = [[x_1, y_1],..., [x_m, y_m]]`

The `maxSeries` function looks like:

```
function maxSeries(datas) {
    var maxY = null;
    var dataLength = datas.length;
    for ( var dataIdx = 0; dataIdx < dataLength; dataIdx++) {
        var data = datas[dataIdx];
        var l = data.length;
        for ( var pointIdx = 0; pointIdx < l; pointIdx++) {
            var point = data[pointIdx];
            var y = point[1];
            if (maxY == null || maxY < y) {
                maxY = y;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxY;
}
```

**Note that in my case I know my case I don't have value below `0`. This code should be updated if this is not the case.**

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised when I first started using JQPlot that it doesn't pick reasonable axis labels out of the box. It's actually easy to fix.

I'm going to assume that you want your y axis to start at zero. If that's not true, you'll need to modify this code a bit.

```
// This is YOUR data set
var series = [882, 38, 66, 522, 123, 400, 777];

// Instead of letting JQPlot pick the scale on the y-axis, let's figure out our own.
var series_max =  Math.max.apply(null, series);
var digits = max.toString().length;
var scale = Math.pow(10, max_digits - 1);

var max = (Math.ceil(series_max / scale)) * scale;

$.jqplot(
    'foo',
    [series],
    {
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: max
            }
        }
        // Put your other config stuff here
    }
)
```

The basic idea here is that we want to round *up* to some nice, round value near the maximum value in our series. In particular, we round up to the nearest number that has zeroes in all digits except the left-most. So the max 882 will result in a y-axis max of 1000.

Comment: Thanks for that! It didn't solve my issue but it gave a good idea on how to solve it. I'll post an answer to explain how I did it